# Change PivotCache from xlDatabase (Range) to xlExternal (Workbook Query) in a existing Pivot Table

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I was provided with two large dataset which I process into one through the use of PowerQuery (I reorganize fields, adapt datatypes etc.). The final Query need to be analyzed with the use of a series of Pivot Tables which I was provided with.

I thought that it would be wise to copy the pivot tables rather than replicating them programmatically, where I would change the source data to a fooRange, while I process the Query, and then change the source to the final Workbook Query.

All seemed fine until I tried to change the Source Data from the PivotCache from  xlDatabase to xlExternal, which raises the following error: "*Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument*"

I don't know if what I'm trying to achieve is possible, any help would be greatly appreciated!

## Sample Code

```
Sub testPivotTables()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets([*Worksheet Name*])
    Dim pivot_table_name As String: pivot_table_name = "TablaDinámica1"
    
    ws.PivotTables(pivot_table_name).ChangePivotCache wb. _
        PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlExternal, SourceData:=wb.Connections([*Query Name*]), _
        Version:=8)
    ws.Visible = True
    
End Sub
```